# MFC - set a background image on a control

Tags: mfc, controls, paint

I apologize for the vagueness of the title, but i'm not entirely sure how i want to go about solving the issue at hand. Basically, i have 2 groups of buttons.  When the user selects a button from one of the groups, i want to set an indicator that that group has been selected. So either a rectangle surrounding them (in blue) or coloring the background (or background image) behind the group.  The end user indicated that a rectangle surrounding them would be nice so that would be preferential.  I have tried overriding the onCtlColor on a group box, but I don't know how to limit the coloring to just the border.  I do know that it absolutely needs to be the farthest back in z-order Any advice?

Example code (i'm aware that it pains the entirety of the box)

```
pDC->SetBkColor(GetSysColor(RGB(100,149,237)));
CRect rect;
testGb.GetClientRect(rect);
CBrush brushBlue(RGB(0, 0, 255));
CBrush* pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brushBlue);

pDC->Rectangle(rect);
pDC->SelectObject(pOldBrush);
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I could find only a way to change the background colour of the **Text** of a group box:</strike>

**EDIT** You can paint anything you want on the Group box!

a) Declare a CBrush member variable `m_br` and create a coloured brush with it

b) Override WindowProc for a group box with ID = `IDC_GROUPBOX`:

```
LRESULT CTestMFCDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   if (message == WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC)
        if (::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND) lParam) == IDC_GROUPBOX)
            return (LRESULT) m_br.GetSafeHandle();

    return CDialogEx::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

```
LRESULT CTestMFCDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   if (message == WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC)
        if (::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND) lParam) == IDC_GROUPBOX)
        {   HWND hWnd = (HWND) lParam;
            HDC hDC = (HDC) wParam;
            RECT rc;
            ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            HBRUSH hOldBrush = (HBRUSH) ::SelectObject(hDC, m_br);
            ::Rectangle(hDC, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
            ::SelectObject(hDC, hOldBrush);
    //      return (LRESULT) m_br.GetSafeHandle();
        }

    return CDialogEx::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better code (at least for me):

```
    void MyClass::OnPaint()
{
CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
COLORREF highlightFillColor;
CPen nPen, *pOldPen = NULL;
CBrush  nBrush, *pOldBrush = NULL;
CRect rect;
GetWindowRect(rect);

ScreenToClient(rect);
BmsMemDC memDc(&dc, &rect);
memDc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

//dc.Re
highlightFillColor =  RGB(0x99,0xB4,0xFF);
nPen.CreatePen( PS_SOLID, 4, highlightFillColor);
nBrush.CreateSolidBrush( GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE ));

pOldPen = memDc.SelectObject(&nPen);
pOldBrush = memDc.SelectObject(&nBrush);

if(leftGroupSelected)
{        
    rect.SetRect(rect.left + 4, rect.top+30,  rect.left + 126, rect.bottom - 5);
    memDc.FillRect(&rect,&nBrush);
    memDc.RoundRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, 8, 8);
}
if (rightGroupSelected)
{
    rect.SetRect(rect.left + 134, rect.top+30,  rect.left + 256, rect.bottom - 5);
    memDc.FillRect(&rect,&nBrush);
    memDc.RoundRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, 8, 8);
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't want to do the painting during `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` (see my answer), it would be better to give resource IDs to the group boxes and retrieve the rectangles of the controls instead of hard-coding the coordinates